# Include python extension module written in C - Error importing MAXREPEAT

Tags: python, c, gcc, anaconda

I have written a Python extension module in C. In order to compile the C code to create a proper .py, I tried to use gcc and Anaconda, but for some reason there are a number of functions in my code that are not available in the python27.lib provided in Anaconda. If I use another python27.lib file, I get far more error.

So, instead I tried writing a python script that creates the extension. The following code was included in the python script to generate the c extension:

```
from distutils.core import setup, Extension
# the c extension module
extension_mod = Extension("chr", ["chr.c"])
setup(name = "chr", ext_modules=[extension_mod])
```

Now, when I try to run this script in cmd, using the following command, I get the error mentioned below. It seems like the problem is some module named MAXREPEAT, but I am sure that if I figure out how to add that one, another will pop-up. Am I doing something fundamentally wrong?

I tried doing something similar with a simple helloworld.c extension, and had similar issues.

```
python testchr.py build_ext --include

C:\Users\ininaa\Documents\Ladi\python>python testchr.py build_ext --include
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python27_win32\Lib\site.py", line 548, in <module>
main()
File "C:\Python27_win32\Lib\site.py", line 530, in main
known_paths = addusersitepackages(known_paths)
File "C:\Python27_win32\Lib\site.py", line 266, in addusersitepackages
user_site = getusersitepackages()
File "C:\Python27_win32\Lib\site.py", line 241, in getusersitepackages
user_base = getuserbase() # this will also set USER_BASE
File "C:\Python27_win32\Lib\site.py", line 231, in getuserbase
USER_BASE = get_config_var('userbase')
File "C:\Python27_win32\Lib\sysconfig.py", line 516, in get_config_var
return get_config_vars().get(name)
File "C:\Python27_win32\Lib\sysconfig.py", line 449, in get_config_vars
import re
File "C:\Python27_win32\Lib\re.py", line 105, in <module>
import sre_compile
File "C:\Python27_win32\Lib\sre_compile.py", line 14, in <module>
import sre_parse
File "C:\Python27_win32\Lib\sre_parse.py", line 17, in <module>
from sre_constants import *
File "C:\Python27_win32\Lib\sre_constants.py", line 18, in <module>
from _sre import MAXREPEAT
ImportError: cannot import name MAXREPEAT
```

Comment: `-py` files are Python source code. How do you expect C code to be compiled to this?

Comment: Hello Olaf, in this example, I'm actually using the distutils.core to get the c code compiled. What should happen is that running the script in python will lead to it compiling the c source code using gcc, and then linking the .o file. If I try a different method to run the Python script, i get the following error in Anaconda:

    'gcc' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
    error: command 'C:\\Anaconda\\Scripts\\gcc.bat' failed with exit status 1